# How to get a retweet button on my wordpress.com blog?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, twitter

Is is possible to get a retweet button on a WordPress.com blog? I see that plugins are not an option, and the only widget that I found was for adding my tweets to my blog. I'm looking to add my blog to other peoples tweets, and I'm surprised that isn't built in, like the FaceBook 'like' widget.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your dashboard, go to Settings > Sharing, and drag the available social networks into the "Enabled Services" area to accomplish this. See http://en.blog.wordpress.com/2010/08/24/more-ways-to-share/.

Answer (score 0):

ReTWEET button is different from twitter's official tweet button. Post it into your articles: `[tweetmeme source="your-twitter-name" only_single=false]`